# When switch is on, the voltage is being calculated as $45V$. What is the voltage when switch is off?

Tags: physics

[image]

When switch is off, the voltage is being calculated as $45V$. What is the voltage when switch is on?

I'm stuck at this problem!

Regards,

Comment: can anyone take a look?

Comment: It should be $36 V$, but MSE is not the best website to ask this question.

Comment: @MathLover That's truly correct! How did you find it out?

Comment: Huh? When the switch is off, the voltage should be higher, shouldn't it?

Comment: Mathlover found the correct answer but I didn't get how.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I've miswritten it, see the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when the switch is open we can write:

$$\epsilon+\text{V}_{3\space\Omega}=45\tag1$$

Now, when we switch is closed:

$$\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}=\frac{\text{V}_{\space\text{in}}}{\text{R}_{\space\text{in}}}=\frac{45}{15}=3\tag2$$

So:

$$\text{V}_{\space\text{measured}}=\Delta\text{V}=\left(\epsilon+\text{V}_{3\space\Omega}\right)_{\space\text{open switch}}-\left(\text{I}_{\space\text{in}}\cdot3\space\Omega\right)=45-3\cdot3=36\tag3$$